# Google Analytics refresh query

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics

My newly relocated (and slimmed down) site provides links with index.html (rather than the folder name followed simply by `\`) where they are required.

Google Analytics has not picked up on this and still reports 403 and 404 errors, which no longer apply.

Do I have to anything else or should I just wait for Google Analytics to refresh? If so, how long would this typically take?

I should mention that I have checked the site with a dead links checker and all seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics doesn't crawl your site and will never pickup on that. Older reports will contain the older urls forever.

Newer reports will show the new urls as you start to track them.